# In ansible can I run docker_compose with parameters?

Tags: docker-compose, ansible

Is there a way to run docker_compose with parameters?
Something like the following:

```
docker-compose run --rm app_service python init_script
```

Now I use `shell` module for this.
Can I use the `docker_compose` module instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `docker_compose` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html#docker-compose-module) suggests that it can only do the equivalents of `docker-compose up`, `down`, and `build`.  None of the other [Ansible Docker modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#docker) connect to Compose at all.

You could use [`docker_container`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html#docker-container-module) as an equivalent to a separate `docker run` command, but this has the same drawbacks as trying to `docker run` a separate container in a mostly-Compose environment (you don't get networks or volumes or dependencies declared in the `docker-compose.yml` file).

Falling back to `shell` is probably your best option here.